# Wait for Async method to complete

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a windows phone app, where on launch of the app, I create an xml in installation location of the app and then I call a method, which initializes the User settings class with the values in xml. 
In the beginning, I check if the xml is already available, if it is not, I create an xml, if it is present, it is read and User settings are initialized. Here is the code in OnLaunched event of App.xaml.cs

```
var isCreateFileSuccessfull = CreateOrInitializeMainXml();

UserSettings.GetInstance().GetValuesFromXmlDoc(HASHNOTESDOC);
```

where HASHNOTESDOC is of type XDocument.

The body of the method is as:

```
async private void CreateOrInitializeMainXml()
    {
        try 
        { 
            StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            string hashnotesFile = @"Assets\hashnotes.xml";

            StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync("hashnotes.xml");
            bool fileExists = await FileExists(InstallationFolder, "hashnotes.xml");

            if (!fileExists)
            {
                await file.CopyAsync(InstallationFolder);
            }

            StorageFile hashNoteXml = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(hashnotesFile);
            Stream hashNotesStream = await hashNoteXml.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
            hashNotesXDocument = XDocument.Load(hashNotesStream);

            hashNotesXDocument.Save(hashNotesStream);

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Problem is that, since the above method is an async method, even before it finishes, control tries to execute the line

```
UserSettings.GetInstance().GetValuesFromXmlDoc(HASHNOTESDOC);
```

and by this time HASHNOTESDOC is null. How can I wait till the HASHNOTESDOC is initialized and only then go and read the user settings?

Answer (score 6):

You have to make the return type of `CreateOrInitializeMainXml` a `Task` and `await` the `Task` in the event handler, which also must be `async`:

So, change your method declaration:

```
private async Task CreateOrInitializeMainXml() { ... }
```

And the consuming code:

```
var isCreateFileSuccessfull = await CreateOrInitializeMainXml();
```

The general rule for `async void` is that you should only use it for **event handlers**. `async void` is "fire-and-forget": you cannot await it, and exceptions thrown in `async void` methods may be uncatchable and crash your application.

The `async` keyword has been described as "viral" -- when you start using it, it will spread through your application as more and more things become `async` in order to `await` other `async` methods. This is perfectly natural and fine. Don't fight it.